# Retrieve memory iPad information in iOS app

Tags: ios, memory, frameworks

Is there a way to retrieve information about the memory of the ipad during running?

For example, i would like to print in the console the use of memory at t instant.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should instrument this instead of trying to print a number. That number is not really useful. What you care about is your application's dirty memory footprint for memory pressure on the device and how much code/mapped ro mem you're evicting to see if you're essentially thrashing and causing performance problems due to memory pressure.

The other info you can get, like device inboard memory and how many pages your app has allocated are not useful because you don't know how much of that memory is wired to other devices or the kernel and you don't know how many of your allocated pages are faults at that point.